# JS Framework incorporated with CruiseControl

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, entity-framework, cruisecontrol.net

Are there any JS Framework that can be incorporated with `CruiseControl.NET` ? Or what's the best JS Framework that have an intensive unit testing feature.

Comment: CruiseControl (and/or CruiseControl.NET) is no unit testing framework, it's continuous integration. Either you got something wrong, or your question is confusing. Do you look for a JavaScript Unit-Testing framework?

Answer (score 0):

The most common JavaScript framework for any .NET project is jQuery - as Microsoft now include it with the ASP.NET MVC framework and I think they now have a stake in it.